# how to put many rows in a dataframe by looping in r

Tags: r, loops

I am looping for example, from a list ["A", "B","C"], 
I will run a for loop
to get v<- for different run it has v1,v2,v3 different values
I want to use cbind("A", "v1") #I want to get three of rows (after 3 times loop) together to form a dataframe.

At the end, I want to get a dataframe which has the format of

```
"A" v1
"B" v2
"C" v3
```

How to get this output?  Thanks!

Comment: If you say list, what is it? A vector, a data.frame with one column, or a real list? And the v#, are they placeholders for something else or just literal v plus  a number? How many of them, and where do they come from?

Answer (score 2):

I may have misunderstood the request, but is the following what you are looking for?

```
input <- c("A", "B", "C")
data.frame(x=input, y=paste0("v", seq_along(input)))
#   x  y
# 1 A v1
# 2 B v2
# 3 C v3
```

Note that the approach you mentioned in your question (iteratively building a row and combining with the existing data via `rbind`) is a bad idea both because it will take a lot more typing (note that I could do the operation in one line) and also because it is inefficient (you can read more about that in the second circle of the [R inferno](http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf)).

Comment: This is a good way through. However, my list has many elements which can not manually input. I think rbind in a for loop will work. Thanks

Comment: @cppython "input" can be a list too. i.e. `input <- list("A", "B", "C"); data.frame(x=unlist(input), y=paste0("v", seq_along(input)))`. The for loop is speaking R with a C accent.

Comment: @cppython how do you have the data stored right now? As long as it's stored in a variable adding it to a data frame should not be difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The part I have been stuck by is that, I have to start with a empty dataframe

```
df <-data.frame() 
for (e in mylist){
   v <- function(e) #get the value our from e by a function
   one_row<- cbind(e, v) #cbind e, and v corresponding to e 
   new_f <-data.frame(one_row)                 
   output <-rbind(output,new_f)
}
```

At the end, I get the right output.